# How to express "with (x) as well" and "even with (x)"

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, particle-で, particle-も

I am trying to express something akin to these sentences:

> 1. **Even** *with* a spoon, he digs well (でも?)
> 2. **Even** *without* a shovel, he digs well

---

I would also like to express this:

> With a shovel *as well*, he digs well [implying he digs great with a lot of tools]

How would one go about this?

I can see how my example sentences might not be best example, but what I'm basically wondering is whether adding `でも` or `も`　to the particle `で` is possible, as it with, for example, `に`

`ででも` does sound rather silly to me.

Comment: How about 洋服を着ていてもハンサムだ or 洋服を着ていなくてもハンサムだ? (I really have to wonder, where you get these sentences from, but anyway.)

Comment: Hmm...  Doesn't でも contain で already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding も after で is possible and usual.  See [Particles で and　も　and でも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5666).

Adding [でも](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=113520600000) after で is also possible, and ででも is not unseen, but the first で is often omitted.

Comment: Not confident enough to make this an answer, but wouldn't `（で）さえ` or `（で）すら` work as well (formality and context aside)?

Comment: @istrasci: I think that they work as well (I have not thought them carefully, though).

Comment: Ah. So でも actually contain both the expected meaning of でも *and* ででも?

Comment: @Daniel Safari: Simply put, yes, but this is not specific to で+でも, but it applies to many other combinations of a case marker and a particle.  For example, when we add でも to を, I think that を is almost(?) always omitted.  You might say that でも also contains the expected meaning of fictional construction “をでも,” but it is not really the case that でも has many meanings, but that the case marker preceding でも is sometimes omitted.  But not always—the combination of から+でも is simply からでも, and I do not think that we can omit から.  (more)

Comment: @Daniel Safari: (cont’d) If this is not complicated enough, we can consider particles other than でも.  I do not know the complete picture about when a case marker is necessarily omitted, optionally omitted, or never omitted.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand what you're saying.
Just like we can't say がも or はも!
By the way, thanks again for helping out, 
the people on this website has just been such a wonderful aid to a hobbyist such as myself!

Comment: @DanielSafari Both がも and はも exist. You should be able to find them in any decent Japanese dictionary.

Comment: @Dono: It is true that particles がも and はも existed in classical Japanese and that they may have been etymologically が+も and は+も, but Daniel Safari is talking about different usages, as you probably know.  We cannot say 太郎がラーメンを食べ、花子がもラーメンを食べた, for example.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Of course.

Comment: @Dono: Oh, was your comment intended to be a joke?  If so, excuse me for spoiling it.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Not intended as a joke. Simply a fact. As a statement, "Just like we can't say がも or はも", this is incorrect. In the right context, one "can say" them. The implication was that both are either ungrammatical or do not exist. Hence my comment. For details, I suggested looking them up in a decent dictionary. Not sure why you felt the need to point out the obvious, hence "of course".

Comment: @Dono: I wrote what should be obvious to you to avoid other readers (including the OP) from being confused by your comment.  If your comment “Both がも and はも exist” refers to particles がも and はも in classical Japanese, then I can only take your comment as either a nitpicking or a joke.  It is along the line of responses “We can say はも because it is a name of fish” and “Not being grammatical does not mean we cannot _say_ it.”  If you are referring to some other words, I do not know what you are referring to and I appreciate a more specific pointer than “look them up in a decent dictionary.”